# Cefsharp Winforms White Screen

Tags: wpf, winforms, cefsharp

I am embeding Cefsharp for Winforms version 51 inside a Windows Forms Host in WPF. 
I have tried running the simple example and using winforms CefSharp inside the Windows Forms Host works fine.

However when I make a new solution Cefsharp renders a white screen instead of the website.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could add your code to help us to understand your issue.
I am using this code to create a cefsharp webbrowser control and it is working correctly:

```
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();

        //validate if the CEF instance was already initialized
        if (Cef.IsInitialized == false)
            Cef.Initialize(settings, true, true);

        chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("www.stackoverflow.com");
        chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may have two reasons.
First is a communication problem. If you are using proxy, then communication could be failed. Then your Cefsharp renders a white screen.
And the second reason may be your code.

```
ChromiumWebBrowser customBrowser;
customBrowser.Load(any_url);
```

This code load "any_url".